# Transfer string to telemetry device using 3.5mm jack

Tags: python-2.7, audio, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need to transmit some data per minute to a telemetry device, that'll be connected to my Raspberry-Pi3. In order to do so, I have made my program in python. Using the pyaudio module.

The baud rate required is 9600, data bits 8, no parity and Stop bit 1. The data that I need to transmit is in String form.  Which I converted into binary equivalent. But none of it seemed to work.

Any leads would be very helpful. Also, shall I use pyserial instead and do the programming accordingly??